# How to hyperlink to a location in an embedded map

Tags: html, maps, embedding

I am creating a blog and have created a public google map with "my places". This map contains several relevant locations to the blog posts. I would like to include a link in each post to the location on the embedded map in another page on the blog. How is this possible? Or this there a better method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the location in Google Maps, just copy the value given when you press the LINK button.

If you are rendering the map (and the markers) on your own page you can use a hash url technique.

```
http://mysite.com/map#loc_3
```

When the page loads, use JavaScript to look at `document.location.hash`, grab the value, then fire the event to go to that marker.